# Localize app store name for all language

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, app-store

I want to upload an app with localized name for unsupported languages.

I know that i can change the name on the `app store`, by language, within `itunesConnect` - but it **can't** be done for all languages - I need Hebrew and it's unavailable on `itunesConnect` list.

I know that i can localize my `info.pilst` for `Bundle display name` but I don't know if this will change the `app store` name or only the display name on the home screen on the device.

So - How can i change my `app store` name to unsupported languages by localizing my `info.plist`? Or in any other way?

thanks!

Comment: Localize the info.pilst only changes the display name on the screen on devices. It does not change the app name in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possibile. App Store name is a metadata information and the only way to edit it is by iTunesConnect as you already said.